# How to parse xml with Linq?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Hi I have xml string like you can see below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
- <Result>
    - <AllItems>
        - <Item attribute="123">
              <SubItem subAttribute="1" /> 
              <SubItem2 subAttribute2="2" /> 
          </Item>
        - <Item attribute="321">
              <SubItem subAttribute="3" /> 
              <SubItem2 subAttribute2="4" /> 
          </Item>
      </AllItems>
  </Result>
```

I would like to get each item in allitems element get attribute values and add them to Enumerable class

```
Enumerable<Item> allitems = new Enumerable<Item>();

public class Item()
{
     public string attribute{get;set;}
     public string subattribute{get;set;}
     public string subattribute2{get;set;}
}
```

How it can be done with using LINQ?

Comment: there is no such class as `Enumerable<T>`. Use `List<T>` instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ to read XML (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670563/linq-to-read-xml-c)

Answer (score 3):

Your example would look like this in Linq to XML:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
var allItems = doc.Descendants("Item").Select(x => new Item() 
{
    attribute = x.Attribute("attribute").Value,
    subattribute = x.Element("SubItem").Attribute("subAttribute").Value,
    subattribute2 = x.Element("SubItem2").Attribute("subAttribute2").Value
});

foreach (var item in allItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1} / {2} ", item.attribute, 
                                                       item.subattribute, 
                                                       item.subattribute2));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's something that will directly translate into your class:

```
var allItems = from item in XDocument.Load("myxmlfile.xml").Descendants("Item")
    select new Item()
    {
        attribute = (string)item.Attribute("attribute"),
        subattribute = (string)item.Element("SubItem1").Attribute("subAttribute"),
        subattribute2 = (string)item.Element("SubItem2").Attribute("subAttribute")
    };

foreach(Item item in allItems)
{
    // your logic here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) which you can use to query XML with LINQ