# Simple question about xml element in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I'm not good in ASP.NET(c#) and XML.
I have a textbox control, a button, and a website url(ex: http://chelseacole.com/question) has content of a xml file, like this:

```
<paragraph>
<text att1="1" att2="2">
        facebook, facebook, facebook, facebook.
</text>
<text att1="3" att2="4">
        twitter, twitter, twitter, twitter.
</text>
<text att1="5" att2="6">
        facebook, twitter, facebook, twitter.
</text>
</paragraph>
```

So what I want is: went I click the button, the result will appear in the textbox control, like this:

```
facebook, facebook, facebook, facebook.
twitter, twitter, twitter, twitter.
facebook, twitter, facebook, twitter.
```

Anyone gonna help me? Thanks in advance! :">

Comment: Could you post the code you use to populate the textbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've understand what do you want to achieve, try something like this:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
```

or:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Parse("<paragraph><text att ... ");

foreach (XElement item in document.Descendants("text"))
    textbox.Text+=item.Value + Environment.NewLine;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check this

[LINQ to read XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670563/linq-to-read-xml-c)

I would not recommend any other solution than this