# Consuming WebApi in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, wcf-web-api

Using WebApi, what is the best way to consume a service in a MVC client?

If the response comes back as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ArrayOfContact 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Contact>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Name>Bilbo Baggins</Name>
    </Contact>
    <Contact>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <Name>Frodo Baggins</Name>
    </Contact>
</ArrayOfContact>
```

How can I take that, get my Contacts out and list them in a MVC3 Razor View using @Model?

There's a [lot of examples online](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20started%3a%20Building%20a%20simple%20web%20api) for the latest preview of WebApi but I can't find any that go a step further and show a client *consuming* the service, say using WebClient.

Thanks,

R.

Comment: Worth adding, the service is fine. If I run var contacts = new WebClient().DownloadString(" http:// localhost:9000/api/contacts"); I get the XML file no worries.

Comment: I would use Linq to Xml. See [this question][1] for some examples.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670563/linq-to-read-xml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could define a model:

```
public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and then consume:

```
var url = "http://localhost:9000/api/contacts";
using (var client = new WebClient())
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(client.OpenRead(url)))
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Contact[]));
    var contacts = (Contact[])serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    // TODO: Do something with the contacts
}
```

Comment: I'd have like to get Alexander's reply workable but Darin's works as is.

Answer (score 6):

WCF Web API comes with a new, improved HttpClient implementation.
Please take a look at [this sample](http://wcf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/66aa503c963c#WCFWebApi%2fsamples%2fbasic%2fPocoService.Sample%2fProgram.cs) (which is included in the source code you can download [here](http://wcf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets)).

[Update]

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var task = client.GetAsync("http://webapi/Contacts");
var contacts = task.ContinueWith(
    t => {
        return t.Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Contact>>();
    }).Unwrap().Result;

Console.WriteLine(contacts.Count);
```

Comment: That looks good but how do I map the xml in the response to my strongly typed objects?

Comment: You can access the Content property of the response and call the ReadAsAsync<T> where T is your type. HttpClient uses the build in XmlFormatter to deserialize your Xml.