# Extract contents from HttpResponseMessage

Tags: .net, casting, wcf-web-api

I'm recieving an object of type `System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage<List<T>>`, how do I get the `List<T>`?

I tried casting the content property and getting a value from the content property via its value property but nothing seems to work.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the .ReadAsAsync<List<T>> method of the Content property.

Please also read my sample from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8430308/90800) answer.

Update:
These extension methods are located in the `System.Net.Http.Formatting` namespace inside the NuGet Package [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client](http://Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client).

Comment: Just a note that you need to add a reference to `System.Net.Http.Formatting`

Answer (score 8):

This is no longer possible. Check this out:
http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/350492