# Read XML file into XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I am very new to C#. I have XML file (text.xml). I want to read that in `XmlDocument` and store the stream in string variable.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Use `XmlDocument.Load()` method to load XML from your file. Then use `XmlDocument.InnerXml` property to get XML string.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("path to your file");
string xmlcontents = doc.InnerXml;
```

Comment: `XmlDocument` does not contain a definition for `Load`.

Comment: I downvoted all of these because none of them worked. As it turns out, I am developing for WindowsRT, and the *Compact .NET Framework* has a lot of these features stripped out. Including a lot of the ones that I need... Such as `XmlDocument.Load()` and and the StreamReader constructor `StreamReader(filePath)`

Comment: @MattClark: I feel your pain - I've been struggling with the vagaries and limitations of CF for two years now - but that's no reason to downvote. The OP did not specify CF, and so there's no reason the answerers would take CF into consideration.

Comment: XML parsers should not be vulnerable to XXE attacks:
https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/RSPEC-2755/

   var document = new XmlDocument();
   document.XmlResolver = null;

Answer (score 18):

If your .NET version is newer than 3.0 you can try using `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument` instead of `XmlDocument`. It is easier to process data with `XDocument`.

Comment: And here's how to load a file using XDocument: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670563/linq-to-read-xml

Answer (score 7):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
   doc.Load("MonFichierXML.xml");

    XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("Magasin");

    XmlNodeList prop = node.SelectNodes("Items");

    foreach (XmlNode item in prop)
    {
        items Temp = new items();
        Temp.AssignInfo(item);
        lstitems.Add(Temp);
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Hope you dont mind Xml.Linq and .net3.5+

```
XElement ele = XElement.Load("text.xml");
String aXmlString = ele.toString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
```

Depending on what you are interested in, you can probably skip the whole 'string' var part and  just use XLinq objects

Answer (score 1):

```
var doc = new XmlDocument(); 
doc.Loadxml(@"c:\abc.xml");
```

Comment: Note the question also requires to store the XML content into a string.

Comment: `XmlDocument.LoadXml()` loads an XML string. To load an XML file by name, use `XmlDocument.Load()` as the accepted answer suggests.