# how to parse xml like this using linq to a object

Tags: .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have following xml as a response to a service not i want to parse this to a key value properties object. but it is not working. response -
I want object with name as Key prop and value as value prop of object.

```
<lst name="industry">
  <int name="Accounting">3</int> 
  <int name="Engineering">0</int> 
  <int name="Human Resources and Adminstration">0</int> 
  <int name="Software/IT">0</int>
```

Comment: <lst name="industry"><int name="Accounting">3</int> 
  <int name="Engineering">0</int> 
  <int name="Human Resources and Adminstration">0</int> 
  <int name="Software/IT">0</int>

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670563/linq-to-read-xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML is not properly formatted. I believe this is how your XML looks?

```
<lst name="industry">
 <int name="Accounting">3</int> 
 <int name="Engineering">0</int> 
 <int name="Human Resources and Adminstration">0</int> 
 <int name="Software/IT">0</int> 
</lst>
```

For that case, you can do..

```
XDocument result = XDocument.Load(new StringReader("<lst name=\"industry\">" + 
                                                           "<int name=\"Accounting\">3</int>" + 
                                                           "<int name=\"Engineering\">0</int>" +
                                                           "<int name=\"Human Resources and Adminstration\">0</int>" +
                                                           "<int name=\"Software/IT\">0</int>" + 
                                                           "</lst>"));            


        var tmpTable = (from i in result.Descendants("int")
                        select new
                        {
                            Key = i.Attribute("name"),
                            Value = i.Value
                        }).ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Value);
```

Comment: You know there is a `XDocument.Parse(string xml)` method saves you having to create a `StringReader()`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using Linq-Xml to select the `int` elements and Linq-Objects' `ToDictionary()` extension method to select the attribute as the key and the element's value as the value in your dictionary:

```
var xml = @"<lst name=""industry"">
  <int name=""Accounting"">3</int>
  <int name=""Engineering"">0</int>
  <int name=""Human Resources and Adminstration"">0</int>
  <int name=""Software/IT"">0</int>
  </lst>";

var dict =
    XDocument.Parse(xml)
    .Root
    .Elements("int")
    .ToDictionary(xe => xe.Attribute("name").Value, xe => int.Parse(xe.Value));
```