# Using XmlTextReader

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, xmltextreader

I am a beginner programmer starting off with C#, and web services.

In the `Service.cs` file of my web service, I create a `ReadXMLFile()` method where I am trying to read an existing XML file, take the data from it and place it to the corresponding properties (DataMembers) that I created in the `IService.cs` file.

My problem is that my code is basically not doing anything. I've tried looking for web sites and tutorials on this but there really isn't much out there, especially for a beginner like myself. Anyone have any idea how I should go about this, because what I've been trying so far is obviously wrong.

Below is my `ReadXMLFile()` method.

```
void ReadXMLFile()
{
    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("ClassRoll.xml");
    reader.Read();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.Name == "id")
        {
            id = reader.ReadString();
        }
        else if (reader.Name == "firstname")
        {
            link = reader.ReadString();
        }
        else if (reader.Name == "lastname")
        {
            description = reader.ReadString();
        }
        else if (reader.Name == "count")
        {
            description = reader.ReadString();
        }
        else if (reader.Name == "testscore")
        {
            description = reader.ReadString();
        }
    }
}
```

this is an example of my xml file

```
<classroll>
  <student>
    <id>101010</id>
    <lastname>Smith</lastname>
    <firstname>Joe</firstname>
    <testscores count="5">
      <score>65</score>
      <score>77</score>
      <score>67</score>
      <score>64</score>
      <score>80</score>
    </testscores>
  </student>
</classroll>
```

Comment: You may find [Best practices to parse xml files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/55828/1048330) useful

Comment: You should share your xml file or a sample of it if it is too big, so we can see its structure.

Comment: You should not use XmlTextReader directly. Use `XmlReader.Create()` instead.

Answer (score 6):

You're probably missing IsStartElement() condition in your while loop:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.IsStartElement())
    {
       if (reader.Name == "id")
       {
           id = reader.ReadString();
       }
...
}
```

Also, it would be easier to use [XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) to read your XML, of course it depends on the file. Here are some examples: [XPath](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9494/Manipulate-XML-data-with-XPath-and-XmlDocument-C) and [LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/670563/1048330).

**EDIT**: after seeing XML file details

You should update your logic to keep track of current `student` and its `testscores`. Also, note that `count` is an attribute. It can get messy pretty soon, I suggest you take a look at the samples mentioned above.

Comment: I agree that you should use LINQ to XML (XElement class) unless you have a good reason not to - the only good reason I'm aware of is that your document is too large to slurp it all into memory at once.

Answer (score 4):

I think, that you get best result using XmlDocument

```
public void ReadXML()
{
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load("<name file>.xml");
    xmlEntities = new List<XmlEntity>();

    foreach(XmlNode item in xmlDoc.ChildNodes)
    {
        GetChildren(item);
    }
}

private void GetChildren(XmlNode node)
{
    if (node.LocalName == "Строка")
    {
       //<you get the element here and work with it>
    }
    else
    {
       foreach (XmlNode item in node.ChildNodes)
       {
             GetChildren(item);
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason its not working because, example: when reader.Name == "firstname" is true but its not true with its  elements value. What it exactly means is reader object reads next Nodetype, which is XmlNodeType.Element. So in this case looking at your XML file, using reader.Read(); function again reads next node, which is XmlNodeType.Text, and its value is then Joe. Im givin you example of working version.

```
void ReadXMLFile()
{
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("ClassRoll.xml");
reader.Read();
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.Name == "id")
    {
         reader.Read();
         if(reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
         {
           id = reader.Value;
           reader.Read();
         }

    }
 }
```

}