# How to read XML file in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have following XML file, i want to know best way to read this XML file

```
<MyFile> 
  <Companies> 
    <Company>123</Company> 
    <Company>456</Company>
    <Company>789</Company> 
  </Companies> 
</MyFile>
```

As an output i need collection of values like "123,456,789" or it could be array of string[]

Can we use Linq to xml? How?

Comment: Yes use Linq. There are 10000000+ tutorials about Linq. Maybe you could start with this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19154/Understanding-LINQ-C

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ to read XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670563/linq-to-read-xml)

Answer (score 11):

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(PATH_TO_FILE);
var companies = xdoc.Descendants("Company").Select(c => (string)c).ToArray();
```

This will give you a `string[]`.

Answer (score 6):

Use LINQ to XML, Include `using System.Xml.Linq;`

```
   XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("yourfile.xml");
   var test = xmlDoc.Descendants("Companies").Elements("Company").Select(r => r.Value).ToArray();
   string result = string.Join(",", test);
```

Output would be:

> 123,456,789

Comment: You can just use `.Descendants("Company")` instead of `.Descendants("Companies").Elements("Company")`

Comment: @ChuckSavage, I just wanted to give an idea, and the above statement also works where you want to avoid nested company element such that:     <Company>123</Company>
    <otherinfo>
      <Company>child company</Company>
    </otherinfo>

Comment: Yep - I was in a critical place yesterday - sorry for that.

Answer (score 4):

In dataset you can read xml file

Following are lines of code to read XML file in DataSet

```
DataSet dsMenu = new DataSet(); //Create Dataset Object

dsMenu.ReadXml("XMLFILENAME.XML"); // Read XML file in Dataset

DataTable dtXMLFILE// Create DatyaTable object

dtXMLFILE= dsMenu.Tables[0]; // Store XML Data in Data Table
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var xmlStr=@"<MyFile> 
  <Companies> 
    <Company>123</Company> 
    <Company>456</Company>
    <Company>789</Company> 
  </Companies> 
</MyFile>";

var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlStr);
var companyIds = xDoc.Descendants("Company").Select(e => (int)e);
```

Comment: @ChuckSavage Read carefully... they weren't actually explicit about that requirement. Collection of *values* or string array. I fulfil that requirement by the rules of boolean logic. It wouldn't take a genius to subvert this answer to produce strings instead of ints. Hardly worth a downvote...

Comment: OP requested "..." or string[].  If you want the vote back, I can't change the downvote until the answer has been edited.  You and I both know, it just takes a `.ToArray()` on the end of your statement to make it an array, but that is what the OP requested.  As is, your answer is an `IEnumerable<int>` which isn't the same as a `string[]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
string pathToXmlFile = @"C:\test.xml";
XElement patternDoc = XElement.Load(pathToXmlFile);
List<string> values = new List<string>();
foreach (var element in patternDoc.Elements("Companies").Elements("Company"))
{
   values.Add(element.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the past, I have used an `XmlReader` and had no difficulties.

MSDN Documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader(v=vs.110).aspx

It is very straightforward and the documentation is pretty well written. A quick demonstration of how to use it:

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(targetFile);

while (reader.Read())
{
    switch (reader.NodeType)
    {
        case XmlNodeType.Element:
            if (reader.Name.Equals("Company")
            {
                // Read the XML Node's attributes and add to string
            }
            break;
    }
}
```