# Select XML Element based on another elements value

Tags: c#, xml, linq

```
<Root>
    <Sub>
        <Name>a</Name>
        <Value>1</Value>
    </Sub>
    <Sub>
        <Name>b</Name>
        <Value>2</Value>
    </Sub>
</Root>
```

How do I select the value of the `Value` element dependent upon the `Name` element?

Edit: In an XDocument, how do I get the value "1" when I have "a".

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use casting nodes instead of accessing `Value` property directly:

```
int value = xdoc.Descendants("Sub")
                .Where(s => (string)s.Element("Name") == "a")
                .Select(s => (int)s.Element("Value"))
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

If default value (zero) for missing nodes does not fit your needs, then you can check required `Sub` element exists before getting value:

```
var sub = xdoc.Descendants("Sub")
              .FirstOrDefault(s => (string)s.Element("Name") == "a");

if (sub != null)            
    value = (int)sub.Element("Value");
```

---

Or simple one line with XPath and Linq:

```
int value = (int)xdoc.XPathSelectElement("//Sub[Name='a']/Value");
```

Comment: Marked as answer since I completely forgot about XPath and should've just used that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, think about it...

you can easily read XML file, just you have to check the condition if the inner text of `<Name>` is match with your condition than you have to read the value of `<value>` tag.

Here is you can get answer for [how to read **XML** file from **c#** code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225051/how-to-read-xml-file-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

you may try this,
may help

```
var results = from row in xdoc.Root.Descendants("Sub")
where row.Element("Name").value ="value"
select new XElement("row", row.Element("Value"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

(assuming `doc` is an instance of `XDocument`)

```
string name = "a";
var items = doc.Descendants("Sub")
               .Where(s => (string)s.Element("Name") == name)
               .Select(s => s.Element("Value").Value);
```

`items` would result as an `IEnumerable<string>` in this case.

If you know you only want one value:

```
string name = "a";
string value = doc.Descendants("Sub")
               .Where(s => (string)s.Element("Name") == name)
               .Select(s => s.Element("Value").Value)
               .FirstOrDefault();
```