# Querying XML using Linq-to-SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, linq-to-sql

Is there a way to query an `Xml` column in SQL Server using Linq-to-SQL?

I want to be able to do contains or Like operator on specific nodes in the XML.

Comment: [go](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24376/LINQ-to-XML)

Comment: this can help you[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670563/linq-to-read-xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, there is no direct/easy way in which you query xml column of database that too using XPath apis, apart from contains/like construct, which gets applied to string content of the xml.