# Dealing with XSD files in C#

Tags: c#, xsd

What is the best way of making queries for XSD tables in C# code?
For example I want to select some results from two tables and who the those results in labels is a form.
How can I do that?

Comment: What does "and who the those results in labels is a form" mean?

Comment: Please restate your question and maybe give example what you try to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can try look into Linq XML

An example of that is here on this site:
[LINQ to read XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670563/linq-to-read-xml)