# How to read data from xml file using linq to xml?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

Trying to read this xml using Linq to XML

```
<Root>
    <shelves>
        <bookNumber>12</bookNumber>
        <coverType unit="H">soft</coverType>
        <pages>100</pages>
        <Weight units="lb">1.2</Weight>
        <chapter sample="1">example 1</<chapter>
        <chapter sample="2">example 2</<chapter>
        <chapter sample="3">example 3</<chapter>
        <chapter sample="4">example 4</<chapter>
        <chapter sample="5">example 5</<chapter>
        <chapter sample="6">example 6</<chapter>
        <chapter sample="7">example 7</<chapter>
        <chapter .................</chapter>
        <chapter .................</chapter>
        <chapter .................</chapter>
        <chapter .................</chapter>
        <chapter .................</chapter>
        ..............
    </shelves>
</Root>
```

Thats the code i am trying with:-. But How will read values all the elements 'Chapter'?

```
var book = from b in xml.Root.Elements("shelves")
                             select b;
    foreach (var s in book)
    {
        booknumber = s.Element("bookNumber").Value,
        covertype = s.Element("bookNumber").Value,
        coverTypeUnit = s.Element("bookNumber").Attribute("unit").Value,
        ...........
        chapter = s.Element("bookNumber").Value ????
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried just another foreach on the chapter elements using `s.Elements("chapter")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var values = s.Elements("chapter").Select(n => n.Value).ToArray();
```

Furthermore, you're reading from the same element (booknumber) over and over. You might want to check your code.

EDIT: to also yield the attribute:

```
s.Elements("chapter").
Select(n => new {Topic = n.Attribute("topic").Value, Value = n.Value}).
ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks. Say each element 'Chapter' has an attribute 'topic'. How will get attributes as well in Array?

Comment: You can use anonymous types. See my post for an example.

Comment: I believe that your current problem spans a bit too much from the original question. Please make another question or refer to documentation or a tutorial to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

You may find these links usefull:

[linq-to-read-xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670563/linq-to-read-xml)

[101 LINQ Samples](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.msdn.microsoft.com%2F101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b&ei=S6KkUKLHErDD0AWQhICQCA&usg=AFQjCNE8mRSbV9y7YZ-Uhiwvtx-rS4CP5A)