# How can i add wrapper to the current xml while defining the keyvalue pair using c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I need to provide wrapper to my current xml from which i am obtaining the keyvalye pair values.
Here is my current code :

```
string SID_Environment = "SID_" + EnvironmentID.ToString();
XDocument XDoc = XDocument.Load(FilePath_EXPRESS_API_SearchCriteria);
var Dict_SearchIDs = XDoc.Elements().ToDictionary(a => (string)a.Attribute("Name"), a => (string)a.Attribute("Value"));
string Search_ID = Dict_SearchIDs.Where(IDAttribute => IDAttribute.Key == SID_Environment).Select(IDAttribute => IDAttribute.Value).FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine(Search_ID);
```

Here is my sample xml as follows:

```
<APIParameters>
     <Parameter Name="SID_STAGE" Value="101198" Required="true"/>
     <Parameter Name="SID_QE" Value="95732" Required="true"/>
 </APIParameters>
```

Please note that this code is working fine with the sample xml but after modifying my xml with some wrappers i am facing the issue.
I need to provide some wrapper to my xml to modify my sample xml as follows:

```
<DrWatson>
  <Sets>
    <Set>
      <APIParameters>
        <Parameter Name="SID_STAGE" Value="101198" Required="true"/>
        <Parameter Name="SID_QE" Value="95732" Required="true"/>
      </APIParameters>
    </Set>
  </Sets>
</DrWatson>
```

But when i do it and run my code it throws me an error.Please suggest.

Comment: [Whats wrong with this solution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18848153/how-can-i-fetch-the-value-from-the-keyvalue-pair-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like:

```
var apiParams = doc.Descendants("APIParameters");
```

Then you can modify your code:

```
var Dict_SearchIDs = apiParams.Elements().ToDictionary(a => (string)a.Attribute("Name"), a => (string)a.Attribute("Value"));
```

Comment: Yeah. thats what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

XDoc.Elements() returns only the immediate child elements, use Descendants instead.

```
var parameterElements = xDoc.Descendants("Parameter");
parameterElements.ToDictionary(a => (string)a.Attribute("Name"), 
                               a => (string)a.Attribute("Value"));
```

Comment: getting a null exception as Value cannot be null,Parameter Name: key

Comment: @user2778482 that means you have some Parameter elements without Name attribute in your xml

Comment: After using this the 'Key' present in next line says it does not exist in context.