# How to fetch particular record from XML file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In SQL,suppose we want one record then we use sql query like

`select * from table1 where a="1"` 
Similarly, I want to access one record according to condition in xml I mean fetch particular record from xml using asp.net C#

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Linq to XML
http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/10/understanding-c-simple-linq-to.html

It's a way to write linq queries against xml.

More here:
[LINQ to read XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670563/linq-to-read-xml)

Answer (score 1):

Look This Tutorial Linq to XML:

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=564