# Does .NET have an equivalent of Json.NET type functionality for XML?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, mono, json.net

I am currently using the Newtonsoft Json.NET library to parse Json encoded data and then later convert nodes to the desired data type.

Here is an example data structure which is already working for me:

```
{
    "ToolUtility": {
        "SharedBrushListModel": {
            "SelectedBrushInstanceID": 786
        },
        "SomethingElse": 42
    }
}
```

And here is how I can interact with this data:

```
// Parse data and collate into groups of properties.
var store = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, JProperty>>();
foreach (var group in JObject.Parse(jsonInput)) {
    var storeGroup = new Dictionary<string, JProperty>();
    store[group.Key] = storeGroup;

    foreach (var property in group.Value.Children<JProperty>())
        storeGroup[property.Name] = property;
}

// Convert nodes into the desired types.
var utilityNode = store["ToolUtility"];
var model = utilityNode["SharedBrushListModel"].ToObject<SharedBrushListModel>();
int somethingElse = utilityNode["SomethingElse"].ToObject<int>();

// Convert desired types back to nodes.
var nodeA = JToken.FromObject(model);
var nodeB = JToken.FromObject(somethingElse);

// Encode back to Json.
var outputRoot = new JObject();
outputRoot["ToolUtility"] = new JObject();
outputRoot["ToolUtility"]["SharedBrushListModel"] = nodeA;
outputRoot["ToolUtility"]["SomethingElse"] = nodeB;
string json = outputRoot.ToString(formatter);
```

The nice thing with this API is that I can parse the Json encoded data without including any type annotations, and then explicitly convert nodes into the specialized type at a later time when this has been resolved.

Is there a way with regular .NET to do the same sort of thing with XML?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <ToolUtility>
        <SharedBrushListModel>
            <SelectedBrushInstanceID>786</SelectedBrushInstanceID>
        </SharedBrushListModel>
        <SomethingElse>42</SomethingElse>
    </ToolUtility>
</root>
```

I would like to achieve this using standard .NET libraries rather than requiring any third-party libraries such as Json.NET.

The trouble with including additional libraries is that a number of issues occur in the target environment (Unity game engine) where multiple assets include the same library.

Comment: do you want to parse JSON into XML?

Comment: Look into "Linq to XML" (one example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670563/linq-to-read-xml), the internet has many more examples...)

Comment: @ManyRootsofAllEvil Nope, I would like to avoid the JSON step altogether.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [`System.Xml.Linq`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace. Here is the mapping of concepts:

- `JToken` => `XNode`
- `JToken.Parse(string json)` => `XDocument.Parse(string xml)`
- `JToken.ToObject<T>()` => `XNode.ToObject<T>()` (Extension method shown below)

The `ToObject<T>` method is not actually on `XNode` by default.  Here is that extension method:

```
public T ToObject<T>(this XNode node)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (var reader = node.CreateReader())
    {
        return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```

Comment: From the MSDN it would seem that this is indeed what I am looking for. Now I just hope that the version of the Mono framework which Unity uses actually supports this.

Comment: If your mono project is targeted 3.5 or higher, then it is supported

Answer (score 3):

C# has a built in capability called [*LINQ To XML*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx). Here's an example of how powerfull the query syntax is:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> partNos =
  from item in purchaseOrder.Descendants("Item")
  where (int) item.Element("Quantity") *
    (decimal) item.Element("USPrice") > 100
  orderby (string)item.Element("PartNumber")
  select item;
```

And you can create XML's using declerative syntax like:

```
XElement contacts =
  new XElement("Contacts",
      new XElement("Contact",
          new XElement("Name", "Patrick Hines"),
          new XElement("Phone", "206-555-0144", 
              new XAttribute("Type", "Home")),
          new XElement("phone", "425-555-0145",
              new XAttribute("Type", "Work")),
          new XElement("Address",
              new XElement("Street1", "123 Main St"),
              new XElement("City", "Mercer Island"),
              new XElement("State", "WA"),
              new XElement("Postal", "68042")
          )
      )
  );
```

Comment: Anything similar to this to do from objects to Json?

Comment: @CesarD Json.NET has LINQ to JSON.

Answer (score 1):

If you use classes and define in them the data, you can serialize and deserialize the data (objects of that class) to and from XML:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(SomeList.GetType());
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(SomeFile))
    serializer.Serialize(writer, SomeList);
```

and

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<SomeClass>));
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(SomeFile))
    SomeList = (List<SomeClass>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```