# How can we read multiple elements with same name but different in number in xml file

Tags: c#, xml

I want to read `<author>` in `<incollection>` attribute. Elements have a same name but different in quantity.

How can I read authors from `<incollection>`? Please help to read
first `<incollection>` there are three authors and second `<incollection>` have six authors.

```
<incollection mdate="2013-09-10" key="series/cogtech/HuangEV04">
    <author>Zhisheng Huang</author>
    <author>Anton Elins</author>
    <author>Cees T. Visser</author>
    <title>STEP: a Scripting Language for Embodied Agents.</title>
    <pages>87-110</pages>
    <year>2004</year>
    <booktitle>Life-like characters</booktitle>
    <crossref>series/cogtech/354000867</crossref>
    <url>db/series/cogtech/354000867.html#HuangEV04</url>
  </incollection>

  <incollection mdate="2013-09-10" key="series/cogtech/PaivaPMMVS04">
    <author>Ana Paiva</author>
    <author>Rui Prada</author>
    <author>Isabel Machado</author>
    <author>Carlos Martinho</author>
    <author>Marco Vala</author>
    <author>Andr Silva</author>
    <title>Playing with Agents-Agents in Social and Dramatic Games.</title>
    <pages>361-376</pages>
    <year>2004</year>
    <booktitle>Life-like characters</booktitle>
    <crossref>series/cogtech/354000867</crossref>
    <url>db/series/cogtech/354000867.html#PaivaPMMVS04</url>
  </incollection>
```

Answer (score 1):

In LINQ to XML:

```
var xd = XDocument.Load(@"C:\myXml.xml");
var authors = xd.Root
    .Elements("incollection")
    .Elements("author")
    .Select (x => x.Value);

foreach (var x in authors)
    Console.WriteLine (x);
```

Prints a list of all authors from both incollections.

But if you want to filter it by key, your query would be something like this:

```
var authorsFiltered = xd.Root
    .Elements("incollection")
    .Where (w => w.Attribute("key").Value.Contains("PaivaPMMVS04"))
    .Elements("author")
    .Select (x => x.Value);

foreach (var x in authorsFiltered)
    Console.WriteLine (x);
```

This will print the list of authors in the second incollection

Comment: Side notes - probably it's better to check exact match when you are filtering by key `(string)w.Attrinute("key") == keyValue`. Also its better to choose lamda variable name which correlates with object it represents - i.e. `i` for `incollection` and `a` for `author`

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered Linq to XML?

You should be able to load your document and then query properties in CRUD manner.

Consider this question

[LINQ to read XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670563/linq-to-read-xml)

That will help you load your XML and then iterate through it and capture the properties you wish to capture.