# Reading special field from variable XML File c#

Tags: c#, xml, system.xml

I have got a file called xmlfile.xml:

```
<Personen>
<Person>
<Vorname>Manfred</Vorname>
<Telefon/>
<Zuname>Fischer</Zuname>
<Alter>45</Alter>
<Adresse Ort="Bonn" Strasse="Neuestr.34"></Adresse>
</Person>
</Personen>
```

There are two problems. First of all are the fields of '' variable. So maybe the xmlfile contains 3 persons or another value (of course it contains at least one). Now I need to print out the 'Vorname' of each Person, how can I do so? I tried this code (just a short view):

```
        reader.ReadToFollowing("Person");
        string isbn = reader.GetAttribute("Alter");
        Console.WriteLine("age: " + isbn);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

But it doesn't print out the age (Alter), how to get it working to print out the age of each person, in case there are more then one.

Comment: You're using older framework bits.  Look into linq to xml for a more fluent interface.  Also, `alter` is NOT an attribute, it's a child node.  `<sample value="this is the value of the 'value' attribute of the 'sample' element" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a quick search and you'll find plenty of resource to read XML via fabulous Linq:

[LINQ to read XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670563/linq-to-read-xml)

For example to extract persons:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(yourFileName));
var persons = from lv1 in xdoc.Descendants("Person")
              select lv1.Value;
```