# C# Read XML Element and Text

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm still getting to grips with C# and I've been looking for ages to try and find a solution to my problem. (This is a practice project to help me learn C#)

I am able to create and write to a XML Settings file but I'm struggling getting the data from it.

I tried using the top answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670563/linq-to-read-xml) but it didn't work.

I would like to get both the element and inner text from the XML file and into a 2 columned list (I'm currently using a dictionary and I'm open to change this if I have/need to)

In the first column I'd like the element name, and the second, the inner text.

I would then simply just like to write out the list I've created

XML

```
<settings>
    <view1>enabled</view1>
    <view2>disabled</view2>
</settings>
```

C#

```
private Dictionary<string, string> settingsList = new Dictionary<string, string>();

private void CreateSettings()
{
    XDocument xmlSettings = new XDocument(
        new XElement(
            "settings",
            new XElement("view1", "enabled"),
            new XElement("view2", "disabled")))

    xmlSettings.Save(FilePath);
}

private void ReadSettings
{
    XDocument xmlSettings = XDocument.Load(FilePath);

    //READ XML FROM FILE PATH AND ADD TO LIST
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ToDictionary` method to put your settings into a dictionary:

```
settingsList = xmlSettings.Descendants().ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Value);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying so quick! what would x be?

Comment: it's argument of the lambda expression.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Comment: Is there anyway I can not display the settings element and just the elements within settings? cheers! Both answers work apart from that

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you have the class

```
public class Setting
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Value { get; set; }
}
```

You then would have to do the following to return a list of instances of class `Setting`

```
var settings = from node in xmlSettings.Descendants("settings").Descendants()
               select new Setting { Name = node.Name.LocalName, Value = node.Value };
```

Comment: Is there anyway I can not display the settings element and just the elements within settings? cheers! Both answers work apart from that

Comment: @ChrisHall you mean in the xml document? No, "XML documents must contain one element that is the parent of all other elements" http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp

Comment: No, I mean what gets returned to the list

Comment: You are in total control of what you return to that list, but I guess that you are looking for a short and concise key-value-pair generating method, like that one Selman22 posted in their answer.

Comment: You can do @Chris Hall

Comment: @ChrisHall Ehsan Sajjad fixed an error in my answer, which I have edited now. You want the Descendants of the Settings-Node.