# How Parse Xml Without serialization and store each node Xpath

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I have following xml file. I want to parse it without Serilization in C#.

```
<StudentList>
<StudentCount>5</StudentCount>
<Student>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>Abc</Name>
</Student>
<Student>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Name>Efg</Name>
</Student>
<Student>
    <Id>3</Id>
    <Name>Ghi</Name>
</Student>
<Student>
    <Id>4</Id>
    <Name>Jkl</Name>
</Student>
<Student>
    <Id>5</Id>
    <Name>Mno</Name>
</Student>
</StudentList>
```

I want to store above xml data in List of Student class

```
List<Student>

Class Student
{
    public int Id = 0;
    public string Name = "";
}
```

Here i also want a Xpath of each value node
For Ex :

```
StudentList\StudentCount
StudentList\Student\Id
StudentList\Student\Name
```

Please help me
How do i achieve this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick solution to get you started:

Create an XElement:

```
    XElement studentXml = XElement.Parse (
    @"<StudentList>
    <StudentCount>5</StudentCount>
    <Student>
        <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>Abc</Name>
    </Student>
    <Student>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <Name>Efg</Name>
    </Student>
    <Student>
        <Id>3</Id>
        <Name>Ghi</Name>
    </Student>
    <Student>
        <Id>4</Id>
    <Name>Jkl</Name>
    </Student>
    <Student>
        <Id>5</Id>
    <Name>Mno</Name>
    </Student>
    </StudentList>");
```

..And select from it:

```
var students = 
    studentXml
        .Descendants()
        .Where(node => node.Name == "Student")
        .Select(node => 
                 new Student {
                   Id = int.Parse(node.Descendants()
                                      .First(item => item.Name == "Id")
                                      .Value), 
                   Name = node.Descendants()
                                      .First(item => item.Name == "Name")
                                      .Value
                 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to parse the .xml using LINQ (check [LINQ to read XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670563/linq-to-read-xml) for an example on how to do this). You should be able to implement your other requirements from there - try it yourself and ask for help if you get stuck while coding :)