# Get dynamic tag name and value in a c# list

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml file from which I need to get all the list of list items as Tag Name and Value. Below is the sample xml.

**XML**

```
<RRs>
 <RR>
  <TagNo1>Value1</TagNo1>
  <TagNo2>Value2</TagNo2>
  <TagNo3>Value3</TagNo3>
 </RR>
 <RR>
  <TagNo1>Value1</TagNo1>
  <TagNo2>Value2</TagNo2>
  <TagNo3>Value3</TagNo3>
 </RR>
 <RR>
  <TagNo1>Value1</TagNo1>
  <TagNo2>Value2</TagNo2>
  <TagNo3>Value3</TagNo3>
 </RR>
```

I need to get a list of items such as Tag name and Value. Something like below,

**Return List**

```
[0]: 
     [0]:
          "TagNo1"
          "Value1"
     [1]:
          "TagNo2"
          "Value2"
     [2]:
          "TagNo3"
          "Value3"
[1]: 
     [0]:
          "TagNo1"
          "Value1"
     [1]:
          "TagNo2"
          "Value2"
     [2]:
          "TagNo3"
          "Value3"
```

I have been googling to get some idea but none found based on my case. Pl suggest me to make the above one work.

**Note**

I do not know **Tag Name** at compile time. ie, TagNo1 / TagNo2 / TagNo3 are dynamic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Deserialize XML document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670563/linq-to-read-xml

Comment: possible duplication http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670563/linq-to-read-xml

Comment: I do not know about the **Tag Name** at compile time. Tag name is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you need to read in the XML using a suitable library such as the .NET XmlDocument class, and then iterate through its nodes using the XmlNode class.  There are other XML libraries available, and each will explain to you in detail how what you need to do can be achieved.