# How to read a tag inside another xml tag in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

How to read a tag inside another xml tag?

Example:

```xml
<site id = "1" clas = "black"><test> Value </test></site>
```

I want to read the test tag inside `<site>`. I want to return what's inside it.

My code:

```cs
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("site.xml");
while (xmlReader.Read())
{
    if ((xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (xmlReader.Name == "site"))
    {
        if (xmlReader.HasAttributes)
        {
            string test = xmlReader.GetAttribute("id");
            Console.WriteLine(test);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason you can't just load the whole XML file into memory, say with LINQ to XML?  Is the real file huge?

Comment: You can use ReadToDescendant to move to the next child element if you want to keep using XmlReader

Comment: Assuming you need to stick with `XmlReader` this looks more or less like a duplicate of [Read Mulitple childs and extract data xmlReader in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38425483/3744182), agree?

Comment: the codes are correct but i wanted to read the attribute too, my code already ***has the attribute*** but i wanted to know how to use an option to read both, some idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use 
`XMLNodeList`
like below

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(sites.xml);
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(doc.DocumentElement.OuterXml.ToString());
XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/site/test");
 foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
            {
                if (xn["name"].InnerText == "test")
                {
                  string  testvalue = xn["test"].InnerText;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`System.Xml.Linq.XElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement?view=netframework-4.8) API:

```
using (Stream s = File.OpenRead("sites.xml")) {
    XElement sites = XElement.Load(s);
    foreach (XElement test in sites.Elements()) {
    // test is now your inner node
    }
}
```

If you wat to stick to `XmlReader`, you can use `ReadSubTree()`. See this [example](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/eb29fd7d-8051-4c62-a652-3c82bdd53285/how-to-read-child-nodes-using-xmlreader-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral).