# how to get child element attribute value from xml to linq in c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Response success="true">
  <data>
    <class name="getId" classValue=" this is a class value"></class>
  </data>
</Response>
```

---

```
string strPath = @"C:\Users\Fale\Documents\practice\xpathNavigator\xpathNavigator\1.xml";
XDocument Xdco = XDocument.Load(strPath);

var list = from i in Xdco.Root.Descendants("Response")
           where i.Attribute("success").Value == "true"
           select i.Element("data").Element("class").Attribute("classValue").Value;
```

How to check response is true and then to get attribute value using linq c#?

Comment: have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670563/linq-to-read-xml

Comment: this is working , its my mistake, i used root,descendants , so it was giving wrong result , var list = from i in Xdco.Descendants("Response")
                       where i.Attribute("success").Value == "true"
                       select i.Element("data").Element("class").Attribute("classValue").Value;

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = from i in Xdco.Descendants("Response") 
           where i.Attribute("success").Value == "true" 
           select i.Element("data").Element("class").Attribute("classValue").V‌​alue;
```