# linq to xml: How to get value of a tag in an element in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have following xml data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mail>
  <id>signUpConfirmation</id>
  <subject>Activation</subject>
  <body>
Hi, You account is activated \nRegards
</body>
</mail>
```

I need to read value from `<body>` tag depending on id I pass.

This is what I have tried

```
var xml = File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\DELL\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\Website\\Website\\Files\\Mails.xml");

var str = XElement.Parse(xml);
var result = from mail in str.Elements("mail")
             where (string)mail.Element("id") == "signUpConfirmation"
             select (string)mail.Element("body");
log.Debug("mail data:" + result.First());
```

I get error :

> Sequence contains no elements.

Also, I want to access the value of id tag as well in the same query.

Comment: `id` and `body` are not attributes. Use `.Element`.

Comment: made the changes. still same error. Question is updated.

Comment: You should probably be using [XDocument.Load()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.load.aspx), rather than parsing a string.

Comment: ...and if you don't understand why a LINQ query yields no results, break it up into pieces and inspect them. Otherwise you could take forever figuring out that `Elements("mail")` won't work either.

Comment: Why someone would downvote this question. Even though it has been asked many times, I didnt find any solution to my issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ to read XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670563/linq-to-read-xml)

Comment: @ Tieson. I googled since morning to solve my problem and asked this question only after all my efforts. link you provided.. didnt work for my issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a couple of problems:

1. The `id` and `body` are not attributes but elements so you need to use the `.Elements`
2. You are using the `XElement` to parse the xml. It will start from the first element which is `mail` and then you are looking for child elements of it with the name of `mail` - which non exist. Use `XDocument`.

Code:

```
var result = (from mail in XDocument.Load("data.xml").Descendants("mail")
              where mail.Element("id").Value == "signUpConfirmation"
              select new {
                  Body = mail.Element("body").Value,
                  Subject = mail.Element("subject").Value
              }).ToList();
```

Comment: @DKR - please consider marking as solved when the 15 minutes pass :)

Comment: one more thing. what if along with ("body"), i want value of ("subject") as well.. Can we do that with same query, I am sorry for this basic question but I am new to linq. thanks

Comment: @DKR - see update :) but please also add this extra requirement to the question

Comment: I have updated question. thanks. I am using result.First() to access which is giving me a complete string, how do I separate these 2 values.?

Comment: @DKR - it now returns an object with 2 properties so store the result of `.First()` to a variable and then access its `.Body` and `.Subject`

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = XDocument.Parse("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><mail>  <id>signUpConfirmation</id>  <subject>Activation</subject>  <body>Hi, You account is activated \nRegards</body></mail>");

var result = from mail in str.Elements("mail")
where (string)mail.Element("id") == "signUpConfirmation"
select mail.Element("body");
result.FirstOrDefault();
```

Here is the code that work.

> XDocument

instead of

> XElement

End .Element as @DKR said.