# Retrieve the GUID present in the Xml file for all message contains the text "Fixed and store them using c#

Tags: c#, xml

This is my Xml File:-

```
<commit><subject><![CDATA[Fixed:Bu| Integer Fields Not Saving with >10 digits [ 3f19d010-c472-4ae6-9d29-b727707fe867 ]]]></subject></commit>
<commit><subject><![CDATA[Merge branch 'iq17' of github.iqsmartapp.com:DEV/EnterpriseDesktop into iq17]]></subject></commit><commit><subject><![CDATA[Fixed:Bug-5 | Regression - [Desktop - Action Menu] - Item Print option do not download the PDF file instead displaying the blank screen in the next window. [ def7b8cb-6819-4380-9a57-5af635f9b70b ]]]></subject></commit>
```

Comment: We really want to help you, but that way how your question is designed does not clearly specify what your problem and or question is

Comment: Please read [ask]. This isn't even a question, it's simply a demand for code.

Comment: If anybody know the answer, please help this person. If anybody know the question, please help us.

Comment: What value do you like to retrieve? Are you looking for `xpath`? clarify otherwise.

Comment: Apologies. I want to obtain GUID from the subject tag. for the message contains the text "Fixed:"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ to read XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670563/linq-to-read-xml)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication34
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                "<commit><subject><![CDATA[Fixed:Bu| Integer Fields Not Saving with >10 digits [ 3f19d010-c472-4ae6-9d29-b727707fe867 ]]]></subject></commit>" +
                "<commit><subject><![CDATA[Merge branch 'iq17' of github.iqsmartapp.com:DEV/EnterpriseDesktop into iq17]]></subject></commit><commit><subject><![CDATA[Fixed:Bug-5 | Regression - [Desktop - Action Menu] - Item Print option do not download the PDF file instead displaying the blank screen in the next window. [ def7b8cb-6819-4380-9a57-5af635f9b70b ]]]></subject></commit>";

            xml = "<Root>" + xml + "</Root>";

            StringReader sReader = new StringReader(xml);
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.CheckCharacters = false;
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(sReader);

            XDocument  elements = XDocument.Load(reader); 
            List<string> subjects = elements.Descendants("subject").Select(x => (string)x).ToList();


            List<string> guids = subjects.Select(x => Regex.Match(x, @"(?'guid'([a-z0-9]+-){4}[a-z0-9]+)").Groups["guid"].Value.Trim()).Where(x => x.Length > 0).ToList(); 

         } 


    }


}
```

---

If you have multiple guids in each CDATA then use this

```
List<string> guids = subjects.Select(x => Regex.Matches(x, @"(?'guid'([a-z0-9]+-){4}[a-z0-9]+)").Cast<Match>()
                .Select(y => y.Groups["guid"].Value.Trim()).Where(y => y.Length > 0)).SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

---

To check for Fixed

```
List<string> guids = subjects.Where(x => x.Contains("Fixed:Bu")).Select(x => Regex.Matches(x, @"(?'guid'([a-z0-9]+-){4}[a-z0-9]+)").Cast<Match>()
                .Select(y => y.Groups["guid"].Value.Trim()).Where(y => y.Length > 0)).SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks jdweng. I tried your solution it worked. Now  say  suppose instead of only two lines of xml i have a file with around 20 lines similar to this. Now for each cdata  i have a message but for some message contains Fixed. For this fixed ones, i want the respective regex to be stored in GUID.

Comment: If you have more than one guid in a tag then simply change Match to Match Collection.  I Updated code.