# How to get the NodeName in XML

Tags: c#, xml, nodes

I have this xml:

```
<data_item>
    <warehouses>
        <wa_1>10</wa_1>
        <wa_2>6</wa_2>
    </warehouses>
</data_item>
```

I need to get the nodeName of the childNode.

```
Output:
wa_1
wa_2
```

Currently, i have these following codes but I get 'warehouses':

```
var warehouseElem = lineItemElem.Elements("warehouses");
var node = warehouseElem.FirstOrDefault();
var nodeName = node.Name;
```

Comment: Okay, so there are *lots* of tutorials, questions etc about parsing XML. I'd suggest using LINQ to XML. Have you tried that yet? (e.g. start with `XDocument.Load` / `XDocument.Parse` and go from there). Currently, this question shows a lack of research.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ to read XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670563/linq-to-read-xml)

Comment: Use node.Name.LocalName which returns a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"Currently, i have these following codes but I get 'warehouses'..."*

You can use [`Elements()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342765(v=vs.110).aspx) i.e without parameter to get *all* child elements from parent, `warehouses`, and then extract the element names from there :

```
var nodeNames = node.Elements().Select(n => n.Name);
foreach(var nodeName in nodeNames)
{
    Console.WriteLine(nodeName);
}
```