# Is there anyway to sanitize SVG file in c#, any libraries anything?

Tags: svg, xss

Is there anyway to sanitize SVG file in c#, any libraries anything?
From client side we are sanitizing the SVG files while uploading , but the security team is asking for a sanitization in serverside too.

Comment: Did you try any HTML sanitizer?

Comment: When Tried HTML sanitizer , its not picking it up as SVG is XML

Comment: Please provide the svg that didn't work for you. HTMLSanitizer should work.

Comment: HTMLSanitizer will not work, at least in the default configuration. It has a whitelisted a set of tags and attributes that does not include SVG elements.

https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer

Answer (score 3):

I'm primarily a Python developer, but I thought I'd throw some research into the issue for ya. I used to develop for C, so I thought I should at least have a basic understanding of what's going on.

`*.SVG` files are structured like XML documents, and use the HTML DOM to access JavaScript and CSS functionalities. Trying to enumerate and script out every single catch for potential JavaScript-based security issues doesn't seem realistic, so personally, I'd just entirely remove all JavaScript sectors that do anything more than define simple variables, do math operations, or reference already-defined visual elements from any uploaded `*.SVG` files.

Since `*.SVG` files are based on XML and are human-readable, this could be accomplished by iterating through the file either line-by-line like a text file or element-by-element like an XML or HTML file. You'd want to go through and remove all the JavaScript scripts that don't meet the above criteria, save it & then convert it to XML and use a standard XML-sanitation library on it, and then convert that back to `*.SVG`. I reckon [this Github library](https://github.com/BerndK/SvgToXaml) and [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44332451/how-can-i-parse-xml-file-type-of-svg) could be helpful in that.

I hope my response was helpful!